# parsec-3.1.0 with custom token datatype

Tags: haskell, parsec, wavefront

parsec-3.1.0 ( http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.0 )
works with any token type. However there are combinators like Text.Parsec.Char.satisfy that are only defined for Char datatype. There doesn't seem to be any more general counterpart available.

Should I define my own versions or did I miss something?

Perhaps there are different parser libraries in Haskell that allows:

- custom token types
- custom parser state (I need to parse stateful format - Wavefront OBJ)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generalized versions of `oneOf`, `noneOf`, and `anyChar` can be built out of a generalized `satisfy`, easily enough:

```
oneOfT :: (Eq t, Show t, Stream s m t) => [t] -> ParsecT s u m t
oneOfT ts = satisfyT (`elem` ts)

noneOfT :: (Eq t, Show t, Stream s m t) => [t] -> ParsecT s u m t
noneOfT ts = satisfyT (not . (`elem` ts))

anyT :: (Show t, Stream s m t) => ParsecT s u m t
anyT = satisfyT (const True)

satisfyT :: (Show t, Stream s m t) => (t -> Bool) -> ParsecT s u m t
satisfyT p = tokenPrim showTok nextPos testTok
    where
      showTok t     = show t
      testTok t     = if p t then Just t else Nothing
      nextPos p t s = -- however you update position for your token stream
```

It might seem that the generalization of these seems missing, but you'll notice that these generalizations here make certain assumptions about the type `t` that may not be true for someone's token type. It is assumed to be an instance of `Show` and `Eq`, yet I can imagine token types for which they are displayed some other way than `show`, and that membership in a class of tokens might be achieved via some method other than `==` and `elem`.

Lastly, once your token type is no longer a `Char`, how you choose to represent position, and thus updated it, is highly dependent on your representation of tokens and streams.

Hence, I can see why a more generalized form doesn't exist.

Comment: The issues you have named can be solved by typeclass:

>  class Token a where
>      showTok :: a -> String
>      nextPosTok :: (appropriate type here)
>      ...

In the end you can always `newtype` your token type and provide your own definitions.

Comment: @Tener - Indeed, that is how I'd do it - but Parsec 3 didn't put the nextPos function in the Stream typeclass, nor define a Token typeclass.